# Selecting age count without intervals

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, aggregation-framework

so what I am trying to is write a query that will return a count of people that are each age - not increments. So the count of people that have been alive for 1, 2, 3, ... 67 ... 99, ... years.

I am not familiar with NoSQL but I know that because time is ongoing, the ages count will have to be periodically updated/refreshed. What I was thinking was to have a collection or something that has a key of the age and the value as the number of people that are the age. When a new person is created, it will increment the amount of people in his or her age - then as I said earlier have something to update it.

What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to actively fetch the amount of amount of people (real time) of all different ages without having a counter. Or if I must use a counter, how can I have the database automatically increment the counter so I don't need to interact with the program?

Comment: You'll want to use map/reduce here. The aggregation framework has some open tickets around this, but have not been resolved yet.

Comment: How does the person document look? Do you have a field with the person's age? And I assume that all of these people are in one collection, right?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah Sorta, all of the people are in a collection with their date of birth as a date field

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using MongoDB's aggregation framework. In order to keep it up to date in real time, what you need to do is the following:

1. Project an `ageMillis` field by subtracting the date of birth (`dob`) from the current date. You will get an age value in milliseconds.
2. Divide `ageMillis` by the number of milliseconds in a year (in JavaScript it is 31536000000) and project this onto an `ageDecimal` field. You don't want to use this age to group because it contains a decimal.
3. Project the `ageDecimal` field and a `decimal` field containing the decimal portion of the age. You are able to do this using the `$mod` operator.
4. Subtract `decimal` from `ageDecimal` and project it to an `age` field. This gives you the age value in years.
5. Group by the `age` field and keep track of the count using `$sum`. Basically you add 1 for every document you see for that age.
6. If needed, sort by `age` field.

The command in the `mongo` shell would look something like the command below, using JavaScript's `Date()` object to get the current date. If you want to do this in Ruby, you would have to change that bit of code and make sure that for the rest, you follow the syntax for the Ruby driver.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project" :
        {
            "ageMillis" : { "$subtract" : [ new Date(), "$dob" ]}
        }
    },
    { "$project" :
        {
            "ageDecimal" : { "$divide" : [ "$ageMillis", 31536000000 ]}
        }
    },
    { "$project" :
        {
            "ageDecimal" : "$ageDecimal",
            "decimal" : { "$mod" : [ "$ageDecimal", 1 ]}
        }
    },
    { "$project" :
        {
            "age" : { "$subtract" : [ "$ageDecimal", "$decimal" ]}
        }
    },
    { "$group" : 
        {
            "_id" : { "age" : "$age" },
            "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$sort" :
        {
            "_id.age" : 1
        }
    }
]);
```

This should give you the results that you want. Note that the `aggregate()` method returns a cursor. You will have to iterate through it to get the results.

Comment: The math is right here, but you really should not use $project like this. While it may seem easy to read, you are asking MongoDB to do a lot of unnecessary work. Think of each $project as a single pass through the entire collection. So there is no reason why this cannot be done in one $group stage. The ruby driver is fairly forgiving on the use of cursor and array and are treated much the same. Fair effort though +1. I only added to explain the other parts.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks for the comment! You are absolutely right. Doing all the math in the `$group` stage is a more performant and concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework is the best approach for this. Mongoid exposes the lower level collection object through a `.collection` accessor. This allows the native driver implementation of aggregate to be used.

The basic math here is:

> Rounded  Result of:
>   ( difference from date of birth to now in milliseconds /
>     number of milliseconds in a year )

Feed the current `Time` value into your aggregation statement to get the current age

```
res = Model.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group" => {
    "_id" => {
      "$subtract" => [
        { "$divide" => [
          { "$subtract" => [ Time.now, "$dob" ] },
          31536000000
        ]},
        { "$mod" => [
          { "$divide" => [
            { "$subtract" => [ Time.now, "$dob" ] },
            31536000000
          ]},
          1
        ]}
      ]
    },
    "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
  }},
  { "$sort" => { "_id" => -1 } }
])

pp res
```